# Glassfish deployement Severe: Exception while loading the app

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

When i 'am deploying my application i have the following error  :

> Severe: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/validation/ValidatorHandlerImpl$XMLSchemaTypeInfoProvider
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>       at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

---

> Severe: Exception while loading the app
>   Info: file:/C:/Users/Administrateur/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Gparc_V1.0/Gparc-ear/target/gfdeploy/Gparc-ear/Gparc-ejb-1.0_jar/_Gparc-ejbPU logout successful
>   Info: [7] timers deleted for id: 98894641828724736

---

> Severe: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/validation/ValidatorHandlerImpl$XMLSchemaTypeInfoProvider

My actuel Glassfish Version is **3.1.2.2**.

Every time i have this error i need to kill the JVM to make it restart or stop the glassfish server and clean and build and deploy my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/validation

appears to be the cause.  Do you have the appropriate jars on the classpath?

**EDIT**

To make it work start downloading the Xerces jar from [Xerces download](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0) .

Once you download the JAR just copy/past in in your glassfish (...\glassfish3\glassfish\lib).

Comment: I am actualy working with a maven project please provide more details to make it clear

Comment: I can't give you more details because i know nothing of your project.  What are the contents of your glassfish lib and your webapp WEF-INF/lib?

Comment: Are you looking for a speciale library ?!?

Comment: You seem to need the xerces jar on your classpath.

Comment: I've resolved the probleme starting with your solution would you please accept my EDIT for your answer to make it complete ?!?

Comment: Why not upvote the question to get some rep replacement ;)

Answer (score 0):

The xerces jar must be added to your ear file. One way do that is to add the following code to the build section of your pom.xml:

```
[...]
   <build>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
       [...]
       <modules>
         <jarModule>
           <groupId>xerces</groupId>
           <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
           <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
         </jarModule>
      </modules>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
[...]
```

**Note**: the artifarct id and the group id migth be different in your case. Check your pom for the correct values.

Source: [Including A Third Party Library](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/including-a-third-party-library-in-application-xml.html)

Comment: it's create an issue `rave: Exception while deploying the app [Gparc-ear] : Expected to find an expanded directory for submodule lib/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar but found a JAR.  If this is a directory deployment be sure to expand all submodules.`